# add day to date using regex

Tags: r, regex

Could someone show me how to add a day to a date using a regex?

Here is my starting code:

```
#Create data frame
a = c("01/2009","03/2006","","12/2003") 
b = c("03/2016","05/2010","07/2011","") 
df = data.frame(a,b)
```

Here's what I like to create:

```
#Create data frame
a = c("01/01/2009","03/01/006","","12/01/2003") 
b = c("03/01/2016","05/01/2010","07/01/2011","") 
df = data.frame(a,b)
```

I tried something like this:

```
 df$c <- gsub("(/.*)","\\01/\\1", df$a, perl=TRUE)
```

But am obviously not getting the results I'm looking for.  Am new to regex's and am looking for some help.  Thank you.

Comment: Like `sub("(\\d+)\\/(\\d+)", "\\1/01/\\2", c("01/2009","03/2006","","12/2003"))`?

Comment: Maybe `gsub("/","/01/", df$a, fixed=TRUE)`? Do you always have empty or `dd/yyyy` or mixed with `dd/MM/yyyy`?

Comment: thanks fellas! both solutions work!  gsub works perfectly, am just trying to learn regexs a bit more.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needn't use a regex if all you've got are values like `dd/yyyy` or empty ones. Just use a literal string replacement:

```
gsub("/","/01/", df$a, fixed=TRUE)
```

that just replaces all `/` symbols with `/01/` substring.

If you have to make sure you only change strings falling under `2-digits/4-digits`   pattern, use

```
gsub("^(\\d{2})/(\\d{4})$", "\\1/01/\\2", df$a)
```

where the pattern matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\\d{2})` - capturing group #1 matching 2 digits
- `/` - a literal `/`
- `(\\d{4})` - capturing group #2 matching 4 digits
- `$`  - end of string.

The replacement pattern contains `\\1`, a backreference to Group 1 captured value, `/01/` as a literal substring and the `\\2` backreference (i.e. the value captured into Group 2).

[R demo](https://ideone.com/E25yl5):

```
> a = c("01/2009","03/2006","","12/2003")
> b = c("03/2016","05/2010","07/2011","") 
> df = data.frame(a,b) 
> gsub("/","/01/", df$a, fixed=TRUE)
[1] "01/01/2009" "03/01/2006" ""           "12/01/2003"
> gsub("^(\\d{2})/(\\d{4})$", "\\1/01/\\2", df$a)
[1] "01/01/2009" "03/01/2006" ""           "12/01/2003"
```